# Can I do a running total with UILabels?

Tags: swift, xcode, sum, label

I have two **UILabels** that add points when clicking different objects, they keep individual running totals.  I wanted to see if I can make a running total those two labels where it sums them and multiplies by another fixed number. Or even just sums them if other calculations aren't possible at the same time :-)

So I have these:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!
```

What I'm trying to do is keep a running total/sum (**result**) of **label** and **label2** as those numbers change, in addition I'd like to do a calculation at the same time... ie: **label** multiplied by the number 2 PLUS **label2** multiplied by the number 10 and the result populates in the **result label** without clicking a button so that it's just a running total. (ie: (label x 2) + (label2 x 10) = result)

**label** and **label2** currently increase their value when clicking buttons so I'm hoping to have no other clicks while the running total calculates.

I've tried many things and so far haven't found it to work, so I'm hoping I can get some help here.  Thank you.

Comment: Please show code that you are using to make the calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add observers for label/label2, and calculate in observeValue func

```
{
   label.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: .new, context: nil)
   label2.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text", options: .new, context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

   result.text = ...
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU!  This was exactly what I needed.  I appreciate your help :-)